# Migration error ruby on rails ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

When I go to local host it tells me this:
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
Extracted source (around line #576):
579

```
  # Raises <tt>ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError</tt> error if any migrations are pending.
  def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
    raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection)
  end

  def load_schema_if_pending!
```

And when I go to run the code "rails db:migrate" It tells me this:

[image]

Comment: You've performed part of a migration, which has failed part way through. Rails is now trying to re-run that migration from scratch, resulting in duplicate column errors

Comment: If you can, drop the DB and then run the migrations again after reimporting

Comment: It says this:Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rake aborted!

Comment: I'm suuuper new to programming, so I'm hiper lost:( haha thanks for the help!

Comment: In other post it says to  : 18

Usually when rake db:reset don't run or work for me, I just delete the development.sqlite3 and schema.rb files and re run the rake db:migrate command to regenerate both files.

i did, then migrate, it only creates de sqlite file and fails again

Comment: Try running `rails db:{drop,create,migrate}`.

Answer (score 0):

As the migration error shows, you have a duplicate column: created_at.

You cannot add the column if it exists already.

You are probably creating this column in a previous migration either individually or with t.timestamps (which adds both created_at and updated_at), then trying to add it again in your failing migration.

Do a `describe articles` in your DB console to make sure created_at exists, and remove this migration.